# groupby on pandas dataframe created with pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How do you create a dataframe from a csv file and be able to execute the same `groupby` command that simply works when creating the dataframe by hand?

Step-by-step i tried to do:

I create a pandas dataframe with multiindexed columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    ('A', 'x'): [1, 2, 3, 4],
    ('A', 'y'): [10, 15, 20, 25],
    ('B', 'x'): [7, 8, 9, 10],
    ('B', 'y'): [1, 1, 2, 2],
})
```

I then add a new column with some "metadata" that has only one column identifier:

```
df["C"] = ["F1", "F1", "F2", "F2"]
```

Results in:

```
   A       B      C
   x   y   x  y    
0  1  10   7  1  F1
1  2  15   8  1  F1
2  3  20   9  2  F2
3  4  25  10  2  F2
```

And i group my data on this column `"C"` - this works:

```
grouped = df.groupby("C").sum()

    A       B   
    x   y   x  y
C               
F1  3  25  15  2
F2  7  45  19  4
```

now i store the dataframe as csv file and read it again:

```
df.to_csv("test.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=[0, 1], index_col=0)

   A       B                     C
   x   y   x  y Unnamed: 5_level_1
0  1  10   7  1                 F1
1  2  15   8  1                 F1
2  3  20   9  2                 F2
3  4  25  10  2                 F2
```

executing the same groupby command on the read-in dataframe results in an error:

```
df2.groupby("C").sum()

  File "xxx\py311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 980, in get_grouper
    raise ValueError(f"Grouper for '{name}' not 1-dimensional")
ValueError: Grouper for 'C' not 1-dimensional
```

I just cant seem to work out what i need to do to be able to groupby the column after reading in the data from csv?

Comment: Hmmm, I think it is not good idea create columns for MultiIndex DataFrame like `df["C"] = ["F1", "F1", "F2", "F2"]`, why create columns this way?

Comment: Using a full indexer is a more canonical approach since you don't have ambiguity on which column is used (that's why `df.groupby('A').sum()` or using a duplicated column name with a 1D index would also trigger an error). Nevertheless, you can take advantage of this empty-string behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas ignores the trailing empty string levels<sup>*</sup> during the `groupby`.

```
grouped.index
# Index(['F1', 'F2'], dtype='object', name='C') <- not a tuple
```

You can [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) your "Unnamed" columns to empty string when importing the data to get the previous behavior:

```
df2 = (pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=[0, 1], index_col=0)
         .rename(columns=lambda x: '' if x.startswith('Unnamed:') else x)
       )

df2.groupby('C').sum()
```

Output:

```
    A       B   
    x   y   x  y
C               
F1  3  25  15  2
F2  7  45  19  4
```

<sup>*</sup><sub>This means that a `('C', '', 'X', '')` name could be matched by `('C', '', 'X')`, but not by `'C'`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I suggest don't assign column to `MultiIndex DataFrame` like in your solution:

```
df["C"] = ["F1", "F1", "F2", "F2"]
```

Better/canonical approach is set `MultiIndex` column, so is possible grouping by tuple `("C",'total')`:

```
df[("C",'total')] = ["F1", "F1", "F2", "F2"]
print (df)
   A       B        C
   x   y   x  y total
0  1  10   7  1    F1
1  2  15   8  1    F1
2  3  20   9  2    F2
3  4  25  10  2    F2

grouped = df.groupby(("C",'total')).sum()
print (grouped)
            A       B   
            x   y   x  y
(C, total)              
F1          3  25  15  2
F2          7  45  19  4
```

---

```
df.to_csv("test.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=[0, 1], index_col=0)
print (df2)
   A       B        C
   x   y   x  y total
0  1  10   7  1    F1
1  2  15   8  1    F1
2  3  20   9  2    F2
3  4  25  10  2    F2

grouped = df2.groupby(("C",'total')).sum()
print (grouped)
            A       B   
            x   y   x  y
(C, total)              
F1          3  25  15  2
F2          7  45  19  4
```

In your solution is created empty string for second level for `C` column:

```
df["C"] = ["F1", "F1", "F2", "F2"]
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('A', 'x'),
            ('A', 'y'),
            ('B', 'x'),
            ('B', 'y'),
            ('C',  '')],
           )

grouped = df.groupby(("C",'')).sum()
print (grouped)
       A       B   
       x   y   x  y
(C, )              
F1     3  25  15  2
F2     7  45  19  4

grouped = df.groupby("C").sum()
```

But if write to file empty string cannot be read back, because is not written to file, so `Unnamed` columns names created:

```
df.to_csv("test.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=[0, 1], index_col=0)
print (df2)
   A       B                     C
   x   y   x  y Unnamed: 5_level_1
0  1  10   7  1                 F1
1  2  15   8  1                 F1
2  3  20   9  2                 F2
3  4  25  10  2                 F2

print (df2.columns)
MultiIndex([('A',                  'x'),
            ('A',                  'y'),
            ('B',                  'x'),
            ('B',                  'y'),
            ('C', 'Unnamed: 5_level_1')],
           )
```